# Determine Taylor's formula for multivariable equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Determine Taylor’s formula for the function $f(x, y) = \ln(x+ 2y)$ at the point (1, 0) with remainder term of order three (i.e., the remainder term contains the third total
differential).

I haven't found any good examples as to how I'd do this.

I know the answer, but not how to get there.

Answer:

$f(x,y) = x - 1 + 2y + \frac{1}{2}(-(x-1)^2-4(x-1)y-4y^2)+\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{(c_1+2c_2)^3}(2(x-1)^3+12(x-1)^2y-24(x-1)y^2+16y^3)$

$(c_1,c_2)$ represents some point on the line joining (1,0) and (x,y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taylor expansion of $f(x,y)$ about a point $(a,b)$ is
$$
f(x,y) = f(a,b) + (x-a)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\vert_{(a,b)} + (y-b)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\vert_{(a,b)} + \frac{(x-a)^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}\vert_{(a,b)} + \frac{(y-b)^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\vert_{(a,b)} + (x-a)(y-b)\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}\vert_{(a,b)}
$$
for the third order terms you have
$$
\frac{(x-a)^3}{3!}\partial^{(3)}_{x}f\vert_{(a,b)} + \frac{3(x-a)^2(y-b)}{3!}\partial_{xxy}f\vert_{(a,b)} + \frac{3(x-a)(y-b)^2}{3!}\partial_{yyx}f\vert_{(a,b)} + \frac{(y-b)^3}{3!}\partial^{(3)}_{y}f\vert_{(a,b)}
$$
plug in your $f$ and points $(a,b)$ you should get your result.

FYI I am not sure where $(c_1,c_2)$ come from

Comment: $(c_1,c_2)$ are part of the remainder term. Basically, since it said remainder is going to be order 3, what you do is basically 3rd derivative of $\ln(x)$, then substitute for the variables. 3rd derivative is $\frac{1}{x^3}$, so $x$ being represented as $c_1 + 2c_2$

Comment: ah ok. I thought I had missed a step. In terms of taking it further, the terms are essentially a binomial expansion (except a little more messy).